# Как скрыть NavigationMenuView в NavigationView

Tags: android, drawerlayout

По задумке хотел сделать кастомный поиск по выезжающей с права панели.
Решил сделать это на основе DrawerLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

  ........

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="ru.search.DrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

твкже в активити прописал

```
 drawerLayout.setScrimColor(resources.getColor(android.R.color.transparent))
 navView.layoutParams.width = calckWidthDrawer()//расчет ширины шторки в зависимости от экрана
```

В самом фрагменте есть тени и прозрачности и они накладываются на NavigationMenuView
Если в layuot фрагмента android:visibility="gone  то шторка выглядит так

[image: drower]

 посмотрел в Layout Inspector пришел к тому что это NavigationMenuView  
[image: inspector]

 Как можно сделать чтоб убрать NavigationMenuView  и чтоб там не было ни теней ничего? Чтоб все что мне понадобится добавлял сам в фрагменте.

===UPDATE===
Помог ответ Юрия, но если комуто все же нужен NavigationView, то вот придумал костыль `drawerLayout.drawerElevation=0f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто уберите NavigationView, он тут лишний. Оставьте просто фрагмент

Comment: в плане лишний?  фрагмент, задвигается и выдвигается вместе со шторкой, если оставлю просто фрагмент, то он станет просто частью экрана

Comment: Лишний, в плане того, что выдвигающееся меню может быть любой вьюхой. Главное ей gravity прописать. Т.е. нужно добавить `android:layout_gravity="end"` к фрагменту в разметке. Возможно, конечно, дело в том, что вы фрагмент прямо в разметку вставляете. Лучше в разметке оставить контейнер для фрагмента (FrameLayout например) и фрагмент добавлять в него программно.

Comment: не знал, спасибо